# Difference between multiple elements in list with same string . Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, sublist

This is a little confusing so I will try my best to explain my goal.  **In a nutshell i'm trying to look at a sublist within a list.  In those sublists, some have the same starting element (sublist[0]) and i want to record the differences between that sublist with other sublists starting with the same element**

```
data = [['o1415', '1', '0', '1'], ['o1415', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '1', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1408', '0', '0', '1'], ['o1406', '0', '0', '0']]
D_changes = {}
```

here is a list with 4 elements . . the first of which has a name, 2nd/3rd/4th elements have digits .

i'm trying to generate a dictionary that has the {name:[then,the,differences])}

for example data[0] and data[1] both have 'o1415' as their first element . since they have the same string for the first element i want to compare the rest of the lists with each other . so data[0] differs in data[0][1] and data[0][2] from data[1] . . . so i want to add 'o1415':['first','third'] to the empty dictionary D_changes.

another example would be 'o1414' which is in data[2],data[3],data[4] and for these lists, one element is different in the [1] position so i'd like to add 'o1414' : ['first'] to the empty dictionary above

in the end i want to obtain a dictionary with this type of content

```
desired_changes = {'o1415':['first','third'],'o1414':['first'],'o1408':[],'o1406':[]}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the attempted solutions you have?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a direction more than a full answer.

First, load up a dict to group like items for further processing; I'll use a `defaultdict`:

```
d = defaultdict(list)

data = [['o1415', '1', '0', '1'], ['o1415', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '1', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1408', '0', '0', '1'], ['o1406', '0', '0', '0']]

for sub in data:
    d[sub[0]].append([int(x) for x in sub[1:]])
```

Then, for a given key, simply look at the `zip` of its values.  i.e. for 'o1414':

```
d['o1414']
Out[58]: [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

list(zip(*d['o1414']))
Out[59]: [(0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
```

We know if they're all equal if it's all 1, or all 0; otherwise it's different.  So just do:

```
[any(x) and not all(x) for x in zip(*d['o1414'])]
Out[60]: [True, False, False]
```

I particularly like the aesthetics of that - `any(x) and not all(x)`.  Python can be beautiful sometimes.

Anyway, `True` means that you have a differing value in that slot.  I'll leave it up to you do do that for all your keys and to get it into the format that you want.

Comment: [[1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0]]
[(1, 1), (5, 6), (0, 0)]
[False, False, False] while using the same lines ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry `any` and `all` check for the truthiness of the collection - i.e. the value of the elements in a boolean context.  Your original question was about a bitmap - where the elements could only be 1 or 0.  That's what I answered.

Comment: oh ok i see the difference. you are right . thank you . what should i research to check if tuples have all the same elements within them ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry I answered that in your other thread.  Any reason you've unaccepted this an an answer?

Comment: sorry about that! i just noticed that i didn't accept it

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. not sure that deserved a -1 vote . this probably isn't the most efficient way but it works

```
data = [['o1415', '1', '0', '1'], ['o1415', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '1', '0', '0'], ['o1414', '0', '0', '0'], ['o1408', '0', '0', '1'], ['o1406', '0', '0', '0']]

D = {}   
for name in data:    
    while name:
        for k in data:
            temp = []
            if name[0] == k[0]:
                if name[1] != k[1]:
                    temp.append('first')
                if name[2] != k[2]:
                    temp.append('second')
                if name[3] != k[3]:
                    temp.append('third')
            for k in temp:
                if len(k) != 0:
                    D[name[0]] = temp
                    break
                else:
                    pass

        break
```