# Understanding any()-all() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm experienced with Python a little, however, still doesn't understand how to use `all()` and `any()`. I'm trying to solve a problem;

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers
>   from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all
>   of the numbers from 1 to 20?

My algorithm was first like this;

```
tp = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
      11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
      18,19,20) #I used tuple so I thought process may faster than list

for x in range(100,100000,2):
    for t in tp:
        if x%t==0:
            print(x)
```

However, before I run the script I realized that my algorithm is wrong because number may divisible by **all** of the numbers in the tuple. Then I remember `all()` function, I tried to change my codes like;

```
if all(x%t==0):
    print(x)
```

But I got `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` error. Probably I have never used `all()` and `any()` before, just saw some examples and I didn't understand. Could anyone explain me clearly? Then I can solve this problem.

Comment: have a look at this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19389490/1082673)

Comment: It’s worth nothing that there are a few languages (R …) where your approach would directly work. However, Python does not auto-vectorise operations. This has got nothing to do with `all` (which is conceptually correct here), it’s just that you unfortunately cannot write `x % t == 0` when `x` is a list. You need to manually map or iterate over each element of the list.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question about `all()-any()`, but regarding the X of your [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What you need, is known as "[least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)", and calculated via a simple formula without having to search for a solution among million candidates (even with such a great optimization as a tuple instead of a list).

Comment: @bereal Yes thanks you're right the problem is about least common multiples basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function accept an iterable as its argument you can pass a generator within , also as you are in python 3 you can use `range(1,20)` that return a generator instead the tuple :

```
>>> for x in range(100,100000,2):
...     if all(x%t==0 for t in range(1,21)):
...        print (x)
... 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but are you sure is this correct? I tried with this number `100000000` and there is no result. Number is so big so probably codes are wrong

Comment: @dively you're welcome .  its not incorrect you can try with `>>> for x in range(100,100000,2):
...     if all(x%t==0 for t in range(1,11)):
...         print (x)
... 
2520
5040
7560
10080
12600
15120
17640
20160
22680
25200
27720
30240
32760
35280
37800
40320
42840
45360
47880
50400
52920
55440
57960
60480
63000
65520
68040
70560
73080
75600
78120
80640
83160
85680
88200
90720
93240
95760
98280
`

Comment: You're right,codes are working. Well then probably the number that I'm looking is HUGE. Any suggestion for algorithm? T_T

Comment: @dively mmm . this could be complecated  , but as a more efficient way its better to use `any` tiil it find an number in specific range that `x%t !=0` it return false !

Comment: Hah! I found the number, I realized that actually my tuple must be `(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)` because before these numbers, all numbers can be divisible. Like if a number divisible by 20 then it may divisible by 2,4,5,10 too. Number is `232792560`. Thanks for the answer again!

Answer (score 1):

`all()` and `any()` require an iterable parameter to be passed to them.

- `all()` returns true if and only if all values in the iterable are *truthy*.
- `any()` returns true if any one value in the iterable is *truthy*.

For your specific problem, you would likely be better off using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) instead, since that can support both an iterable and a function.

Comment: Could you give me a tip that how can I use them in my algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

`any()` and `all()` take lists, not equations.  While the concepts come from mathematics, these functions operate on lists of values.  Maybe you want:

```
for x in range(100,10000,2):
    if all([x%t==0 for t in tp]):
        print(x)
```