# I am trying the following code...if atleast one member of the list do not match.....print False

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, overlapping

This is what it looked like for me:  I do not understand why it is not printing false

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b=  [11,6,7,8,9]

def overlapping(a,b):
   bool= True 
   for x in range(len(a)):
     for y in range(len(b)):
          if b[y]==a[x]:
             check("True")
             break

def check(str):
      if str =="True":
           print "True"
      else:
           print "False"

overlapping(a,b)
```

Comment: Because you only call `check` in the `True` case? And why are you passing it a *string*?!

Comment: Check out [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in Python. It can be a common pitfall when you are getting started.

Answer (score 0):

there is not need to loop twice: Do like this, Use `set`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b =  [11,6,7,8,9]
if set(a) & set(b):
    print "true"
else:
    print "False"
```

Make it more pythonic:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [11,6,7,8,9]
def overlapping(a, b):
    return bool(set(a) & set(b)) 
overlapping(a, b)
```

Comment: `len(set(a) & set(b)) > 0` is definitly _less_ pythonic than a mere `set(a) & set(b)`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you explain me??

Comment: all Python objects have a truth value in a boolean context. In the case of builtin sequences or container types (dicts, sets, lists, tuples, strings etc), an empty object has a False value. So the pythonic idiom  is `if container:`, not `if len(container) > 0`.  If you really want to return a strictly boolean value it should be `return bool(set(a) & set(b))`

Answer (score 0):

Using [method any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) and generator expression

**Code:**

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2=  [11,6,7,8,9]

def overlapping(list1,list2):

    return any( value in list2 for value in list1)

print overlapping(list1,list2)
```

**Making changes to your code:**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b=  [11,6,7,8,9]

def overlapping(a,b):
    for x in a:
        if x in b:
            check("True")
            break
    else:
        check("False")


def check(strs):
    print strs

overlapping(a,b)
```

**Notes:**

There is no need to call function check since it prints the same value you could just print it

Comment: `any` return true or false, you dont need to give if condition, only `return any( value in list2 for value in list1)` should work

Comment: the list comprehension is useless here, you get the same result without the overhead of building list with a generator expression `any(value in list2 for value in list1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: a = [1,2,3,4,5]
   ...: b=  [11,6,7,8,9]
   ...: 
   ...: def overlapping(a,b):
   ...:     my_break = False
   ...:     for x in range(len(a)):
   ...:         if my_break: break
   ...:         for y in range(len(b)):
   ...:             if my_break: break
   ...:             if b[y]==a[x]:
   ...:                 check("True")
   ...:             else:
   ...:                 check("False")
   ...:                 my_break = True
   ...: 
   ...: def check(string):
   ...:     if string == "True":
   ...:        print "True"
   ...:     else:
   ...:        print "False"
   ...: 
   ...: overlapping(a,b)
   ...: 
False
```

or

```
In [4]: def overlapping(a, b):
   ...:     return any(x in b for x in a)
   ...: 

In [5]: overlapping(a, b)
Out[5]: False
```

Also don't use `str` word, its built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `return` instead of `break`

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b=  [33,6,7,8,9]

def overlapping(a,b):
    bool= True 
    for x in range(len(a)):
         for y in range(len(b)):
            if b[y]==a[x]:
                return(check("True"))

    return(check("False"))

def check(str):
      if str =="True":
           print "True"
      else:
           print "False"

overlapping(a,b)
```