# Python's all() not giving the expected result checking a list of small numbers are less than some value

Tags: python, function, built-in

In a python console (using 2.7) if I put in the following code:

```
vals = [1.2e-5, 1.5e-5, 3.2e-5, 4.5e-5]
for val in vals: print val < 0.001,
```

The output is `True True True True` as expected.

But! Here is my problem, if I try `all(vals) < 0.001` it returns false?

Is it the number formatting giving it problems or something else? If I do this again but replace the vals list with `vals = [2,2,2,2]` and check for `< 3` I get the desired output both ways!

**EDIT**
Helpful answers, it is interesting to note that all([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]) evaluates to True, but 0.1 == True evaluates to False? What's up with this? Is it that a "nonzero" value will evaluate to True but is not actually "True"?

Comment: Check [How Python's any and all functions work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: @sam2090 what's crazy is that I had actually read that, and I still couldn't see what I was doing wrong!! Guess it comes from staring at something for too long. All sorted now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage is wrong. `all(x < 0.001 for x in vals)` should be okay.

`all(vals) < 0.001` will check whether all `vals` is truthy, then compare the `True` or `False` you get as the result with `0.001`, which is weird.

Comment: You are correct that I have used it incorrectly, but can you add any information regarding the edit I added to my question?

Comment: `int(True) == 1`; `int(False) == 0`. Consequently, `True == 1` and `False == 0`. How that relates to `< 0.001` should be obvious now :)

Comment: @Amadan: you don't even need the `int` calls, since `bool` is a subclass of `int`. `True == 1` is `True`.

Comment: @Blckknght: yeah; I wrote it so that the point was lost; but I meant that if you evaluate `int(True)`, you can literally see in the console that it prints `1`.

Comment: @Blckknght cool to know it is a subclass of int, definitely makes things obvious. Also thanks for the clarification Amadan

Answer (score 2):

`all(vals)` checks whether all the values are boolean True (i.e., nonzero).  That is True.  True is not less than `0.001`.

I think you want something like `all(val < 0.001 for val in vals)`.

Comment: You are correct that I have used it incorrectly, but can you add any information regarding the edit I added to my question?