# Changing the color of pixels between a certain range

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the color of a certain image to a new color. But when running the code below. The following error appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last)
>   File "/home/vagner/PycharmProjects/TestesDeBorda/DesenharRetangulo.py", 
>   line 16, in
>
> ```
> if (image[i, j] > minCorAgua - image[i, j] < maxCorAgua).all():
> ```
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

```
import cv2    

minCorAgua = (108,110,115)
maxCorAgua = (166,163,162)
i = 0
j = 0

#video = cv2.VideoCapture('TesteVideoMelhor.MOV')
#ret, frame = video.read()
imagem = cv2.imread('PegarPixelsDaAgua.png')

while(i < imagem.shape[1]):
    while(j < imagem.shape[0]):
        if (imagem[i,j] > minCorAgua and imagem[i,j] < maxCorAgua):
            imagem[i,j] = (255,255,255)
    j = j + 1
i = i + 1

cv2.imshow('teste', imagem)
```

Comment: It's not specific to this error but the indentation on your code seems to be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip to 3 for a numpy solution.

**1. Use `all`**

```
if (all(imagem[i,j] > minCorAgua) and all(imagem[i,j] < maxCorAgua)):
```

Why? [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

When you do `imagem[i,j] > minCorAgua`, python compares each element of the array  `imagem[i,j]` against each element in `minCorAgua`  and will return an array.

```
>>>imagem[i,j] > minCorAgua 
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>imagem[i,j] < maxCorAgua 
array([ True,  False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You cannot do `if (a and b)` when a and b are lists, arrays, or other iterables, to check if all elements in `a` and `b` are true without using the function `all`. This function will return True if every element of the array is True.

2. **Don't use `while` use `for i in range(imagem.shape[0]):`**

The `range()` function will return a list and the `for` statement will iterate through the list.

```
>>>range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, you don't need to increment and initialize `i` and `j`, making your code cleaner.

```
for i in range(imagem.shape[1]):
    for j in range(imagem.shape[0]):
        if (all(imagem[i,j] > minCorAgua) and all(imagem[i,j] < maxCorAgua)):
            imagem[i,j] = (255,255,255)
```

3. **A [Numpy way](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to do this**

```
import numpy as np

minCorAgua = (108,110,115)
maxCorAgua = (166,163,162)

bool_pixels = np.all(((imagem>minCorAgua) & (imagem<maxCorAgua)), axis = 2)
imagem[bool_pixels] = (255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: @VagnerGarcia Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or another one solved your issue, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.