# Why does python all() function return true for a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that the built-in `all()` function returns true when all elements of the iterable are true. But when I create a tuple and give it 2 random integers as elements, it returns true. Why is that?

For example:

```
tup = 1234 , 5678
```

and call the `all()` function on it:

```
print ( all(t) ) 
>>> True
```

I'm confused because I thought python could only return true or false when a boolean operation has been performed.

But I haven't performed a boolean operation, I only gave `all()` 2 integers. I didn't say for example `2>= 1`. So why does `all()` return true for my tuple? Or is that just the default answer?

Comment: `bool(a)` evaluates to `True` for all integers `a` except `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19389957/5633503

Comment: Rather than `True`, think *truthy* (for the common Python definition of what that means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any non-zero number or non-empty sequence evaluates to `True`.

```
In [1]: bool(123)
Out[1]: True

In [2]: bool(0)
Out[2]: False

In [3]: bool("0")
Out[3]: True

In [4]: bool("")
Out[4]: False

In [5]: bool([0])
Out[5]: True

In [6]: bool([])
Out[6]: False
```

etc. This allows you to write elegant, concise statements like

```
if score:
```

instead of

```
if score != 0:
```

or

```
if sequence:
```

instead of

```
if len(sequence) > 0:
```

Comment: Also: `bool(None)` is `False`. This probably comes up quite often.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.def all(iterable):
2.    for element in iterable:
3.        if not element:
4.            return False
5.    return True
```

This is the definition of built-in all function in python . not element in the 3rd line must be returning false in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption, "Python could only return true or false when a boolean operation has been performed" is not correct.

The objects defined in Python library:`None`, `False`, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`, `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}` are considered `False`. Any other values (or objects, even classes and functions) are considered True. Read: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Therefore, both of the followings are `True`:

```
tup = 1234 , 5678
if(tup):
    print 'True'
>> True

def a_func():
    print 'This is a function'
if(a_func):
    print 'True'
>> True
```

**all(single_parameter_iterator)** is a method in Python which returns true if all the values of the iterator passed to it is True.
Read: [all() method in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all)

What is an iterator?

- We use `for statement` for looping over a list.
- If we use it with a `string`, it loops over its characters.
- If we use it with a `dictionary`, it loops over its keys.
- If we use it with a `file`, it loops over lines of the file.

Source: [Iterators in Python](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)

You already gave the answer yourself:

> "I know that the built in function all () returns true when all
>   elements of the iterable are true."