# How does the "all" function in Python work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I searched for understanding about the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function in Python, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work), according to here:

> [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) will return `True` only when all the elements are Truthy.

But when I work with this function it's acting differently:

```
'?' == True   # False
'!' == True   # False
all(['?','!']) # True
```

Why is it that when all elements in input are `False` it returns `True`? Did I misunderstand its functionality or is there an explanation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> only when all the elements are *Truthy*.

Truthy != `True`.

`all` essentially checks whether `bool(something)` is `True` (for all `something`s in the iterable).

```
>>> "?" == True
False
>>> "?" == False # it's not False either
False
>>> bool("?")
True
```

Comment: Only `bool("")` is False (in string) ? every non empty string is True?

Answer (score 1):

'?' and '!' are both truthy since they are non-empty Strings.

There's a difference between `True` and "truthy". Truthy means that when coerced, it can evaluate to `True`. That's different from it being `==` to `True` though.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment. I updated the second half of my answer since I misinterpreted him.

Answer (score -2):

all() function is used when we want to check that if all the items in a list are iterable or not.
For ex : 
`x=[1,2,3,4,5]
 all(x)`
It will return True.