# Find tuple structure containing an unknown value inside a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have list of tuples:

```
list = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
```

Is there a way in Python to write something like

```
if (1, *) in list: do things
```

where `*` means "*I don’t care about this value*"? So we are checking if there is a tuple with `1` at the first position and with whatever value on the second one.

As far as I know there are special mechanisms in other languages, but I just don’t know the name of this particular problem. So is there similar behavior in Python?

*P.S.:* I know that I can use list comprehensions here. I am just interested in this particular mechanism.

Comment: Side note: don't name your variable `list`. This will clash with the `list` function and data type from the Python standard library.

Comment: Related: [How Python's any and all functions work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19389490)

Comment: You have selected the wrong answer. -1

Comment: Finally realized what this makes me think of: databases. You are effectively wanting something along the lines of `SELECT * IN collection WHERE column1 = 1`

Comment: @AaronHall I'm here not for upvotes but for the answer and to be honest in my code I used list comprehension (without 'any' function). I selected  answer because it's answers the question "Is there native placeholder mechanism in python?".

Comment: @Justin: not really. They are testing any such rows *exist*, they are not selecting them.

Comment: @Justin: but you want to avoid retrieving all matching rows, when all you need to know the *existence* of a row.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes of course. I was just pointing out a similarity between this question and database operations.

Comment: @Justin: sure, but then wrap that SELECT in a `WHERE EXISTS` clause.

Comment: The name of the language feature is QbE (query by example), unification (Prolog), or simply "pattern matching".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A placeholder object like you're asking for isn't supported natively, but you can make something like that yourself:

```
class Any(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
ANYTHING = Any()

lst = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
```

The `__eq__` method defines how two objects test for equality. (See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html for details.) Here, `ANYTHING` will always test positive for equality with any object. (Unless that object also overrode `__eq__` in a way to return False.)

The `in` operator merely calls `__eq__` for each element in your list. I.e. `a in b` does something like:

```
for elem in b:
    if elem == a:
        return True
```

This means that, if you say `(1, ANYTHING) in lst`, Python will first compare `(1, ANYTHING)` to the first element in `lst`. (Tuples, in turn, define `__eq__` to return True if all its elements' `__eq__` return True. I.e. `(x, y) == (a, b)` is equivalent to `x==a and y==b`, or `x.__eq__(a) and y.__eq__(b)`.)

Hence, `(1, ANYTHING) in lst` will return True, while `(3, ANYTHING) in lst` will return False.

Also, note that I renamed your list `lst` instead of `list` to prevent name clashes with the Python built-in `list`.

Comment: Pre-empting other comments: technically when doing trickery that involves redefining `__eq__`, one should also redefine `__ne__`, but that's not needed in this case. Also note that `ANYTHING==x` will return True regardless of `x`'s value, but the same is not necessarily true of `x==ANYTHING`.

Comment: There are other answers which talk about built in 'any' , Why do you think this isn't supported natively?

Comment: @AlokThakur: There's two different functionalities here that sound very similar. It is indeed natively supported to check if any element of an iterable is True, but the OP didn't sound like that's what he wanted to know. The second issue, which is far more interesting, is having an object (`*` in OP's post, `ANYTHING` in mine) which is a placeholder for "any value", which is unrelated to the functionality provided by the `any` built-in. (That said, I edited my answer to clarify what isn't natively supported.)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. But could you clarify what actually happens in redefining __eq__? It's not clear for me how this goes from class Any to (1, ANYTHING) in lst example. Does it means that in class Any every comparison will return True?

Comment: @selotec I added a bit of explanation to the answer, but in short: yes, any instance of the `Any` class will (almost) always test `True` for equality tests. (Not quite always: imagine if I also made a `Nothing` class, and defined its `__eq__` to always return False!)

Comment: @acdr Based on which comes first will not `NOTHING == ANYTHING` be false, while `ANYTHING == NOTHING` is true? Hmmm... Interesting.

Comment: @holroy That's indeed exactly how it works! `NOTHING == ANYTHING` will call `NOTHING.__eq__(ANYTHING)`, whereas `ANYTHING == NOTHING` will call `ANYTHING.__eq__(NOTHING)`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `in` will directly call `__eq__`?  I believe there are situations where *before* calling `__eq__` the interpreter will simply check the memory addresses. This would make `x = (1, NOTHING); x  in [x]` return `True` even if you expected it to return `False` due to how `NOTHING.__eq__` behaves... However I'm not sure if `in` is one of these.

Comment: @Bakuriu Looks like you're right. From my NOTHING example above, `NOTHING in [NOTHING]` still returns true. I'd guess this is implemented under the hood as something like `(x is y) or (x.__eq__(y))` rather than just `x.__eq__(y)` but don't quote me on that. A quick google search doesn't teach me the exact workings of the `in` operator.

Comment: You can look at the sources on [`hg.python.org`](https://hg.python.org/). The `in` operator is compiled to a `COMPARE_OP` bytecode and you can then go look in the [`Python/ceval.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l2707) file which contains the interpreter main loop, and you see that comparisons are done using [`cmp_outcome`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l5088) the `in` case calls [`PySequence_Contains`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c#l1915)

Comment: which calls [`_PySequence_IterSearch`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c#l1915) which simply calls `PyIter_Next` and uses [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l723) which finally uses memory address comparison. In fact there is a comment about forcing identity implying equality.

Comment: Be VERY CAREFUL using solutions like this... the given solution will work for a list, but will NOT work for something like a dictionary: `d = { (1,1): 'A' }; (1, ANYTHING) in d` return `False`. This is because in this case, it's actually computing the hash of the source and looking up directly. Basically, anytime the object's lookup is O(1), it won't work without explicitly converting it to an O(n) lookup (e.g. `(1, ANYTHING) in d.keys()` does return `True`...). Just make sure you don't blindly use this...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Actually using `.keys()` doesn't help at all if you are using non-outdated versions of python, since it returns a view (which is basically a `set`). Use `x in list(d.keys())` instead...

Comment: good point... i'm still on python 2.7, where `keys()` is still a list.

Comment: If I saw code like this in a review I would kill it with fire and insist it be done as Martijn suggested.

Answer (score 71):

You can use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(t[0] == 1 for t in yourlist):
```

This efficiently tests and exits early if `1` is found in the first position of a tuple.

Comment: For what it's worth, I down-voted this answer, despite the fact that this is how I would solve OP's posted problem. However, considering the title of the thread, I don't think this answer (or any other current ones apart from my own) actually say what the OP wants to know (namely how to get a variable with "any" value).

Comment: @acdr: that's a different interpretation of the question. I'm sorry you don't find my answer helpful or enlightening, but this is a correct way to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: It's a good solution, thanks, but a question was a slightly different.

Comment: @acdr: see, I don't think there was any need to down vote just because multiple interpretations are possible. Leave it to the OP to decide what interpretation they feel fits their question.

Comment: The difference between this and OP is that this approach will iterate over `yourlist`. This is okay when `yourlist` is actually a `list` but when it is for example a 2d-tree, things will be more expensive.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: alternative data structures are entirely out of scope here; the OP did post a list in their question.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I doubt a 2d-tree would be able to cope with an ANY key either, such as the one in the accepted answer..

Comment: actually, _both_ approaches iterate over `yourlist`; it's just that this one does it explicitly, and the other does it implicitly. because it's explicit, this one will iterate even when the source container does not normally iterate for `__contains__` (e.g. hash lookup or other shortcut).

Comment: The OP should edit the Q, since its title directly clashes with `if (1, *) in list: do things` given in the Q's body. This answer is a 100% fit for the *code*.

Answer (score 11):

*Not all of my solution methods provided below will be necessarily efficient. My goal is to demonstrate every possible solution method I can think of - at the end of my answer I provide "benchmark" results to show why or why not you should use one certain method over another. I believe that is a good way of learning, and I will shamelessly encourage such learning in my answers.*

---

#### Subset + hash `set`s

```
>>> a_list = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
>>>
>>> set([l[0] for l in a_list])
{1, 2}
>>>
>>> 1 in set([l[0] for l in a_list])
True
```

---

#### `map()`, and anonymous functions

```
>>> a_list = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
>>>
>>> map(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)
[True, True, False]
>>>
>>> True in set(map(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list))
True
```

---

#### `filter` and anonymous functions

```
>>> a_list = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
>>>
>>> filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)
[(1,5), (1,7)]
>>>
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)) > 0  # non-empty list
True
```

---

### MICROBENCHMARKS

#### Conditions

- 1000 items
- 100K repetition
- 0-100 random range
- Python 2.7.10, IPython 2.3.0

#### Script

```
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit

N_ITEMS = 1000
N_SIM = 1 * (10 ** 5)  # 100K = 100000

a_list = [(randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(N_ITEMS)]

set_membership_list_comprehension_time = timeit(
    "1 in set([l[0] for l in a_list])",
    number = N_SIM,
    setup="from __main__ import a_list"
)

bool_membership_map_time = timeit(
    "True in set(map(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list))",
    number = N_SIM,
    setup="from __main__ import a_list"
)

nonzero_length_filter_time = timeit(
    "len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)) > 0",
    number = N_SIM,
    setup="from __main__ import a_list"
)

any_list_comprehension_time = timeit(
    "any(t[0] == 1 for t in a_list)",
    number = N_SIM,
    setup="from __main__ import a_list"
)

results = {
    "any(t[0] == 1 for t in a_list)": any_list_comprehension_time,
    "len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)) > 0": nonzero_length_filter_time,
    "True in set(map(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list))": bool_membership_map_time,
    "1 in set([l[0] for l in a_list])": set_membership_list_comprehension_time
}

pprint(
    sorted(results.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
)
```

#### Results (in seconds)

```
[('any(t[0] == 1 for t in a_list)', 2.6685791015625),     # winner - Martijn
 ('1 in set([l[0] for l in a_list])', 4.85234808921814),
 ('len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list)) > 0', 7.11224889755249),
 ('True in set(map(lambda x: x[0] == 1, a_list))', 10.343087911605835)]
```

*Who's got the last laugh now? ... Martijn (at least I tried)*

*MORAL OF THE STORY: Don't spend more than 10 minutes "proving" your inferior solution is faster and more efficient on a small test data, when another user's answer is the de-facto correct one*

Comment: The `map()` defeats the purpose of `any()`; you now created a list with all boolean outcomes, up front. That's why you normally use a *generator expression* with `any()`.

Comment: You created a set from a list; you can create the set directly, again with a generator expression rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: Can you retest with larger datasets too? 3 elements is hardly a good test of the methods.

Comment: With `a_list = [(random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(1000)]` (shared between tests, don't regenerate), and 100k repetitions, `any()` takes 0.18 seconds on Python 3.5. The other methods still take seconds (orders of magnitude slower). That's because your `set()` method still has to process **all** tuples, while `any()` only processes as many tuples as it takes to find one example.

Comment: Wow I spent time on this more than I should have. But @MartijnPieters, I concede; I have updated my script because I did close to what your parameters are. I'm glad I did this though, it taught me not to be cocky and that we can all learn a thing or two from each other. Except maybe you. Maybe you're already a know it all. I don't know. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You could also add the now accepted approach (using a sentinel object that matches anything), and add a worst case and best case test (long list with no matches and long list with the first tuple matching).

Comment: I'm sorry you find my feedback so.. condescending? I could just refrain from giving you honest feedback. There really is no need to be so rude when receiving it, at any rate.

Comment: Wait I didn't find your feedback condescending... I'm actually appreciative of it. We're all here to learn though and I'm all for being a helpful member of the SO community; just out of curiosity how did you infer I was threatened...? I appreciate honest feedback, so that was genuine gratitude.

Comment: Perhaps ask someone else to read *[..] it taught me not to be cocky and that we can all learn a thing or two from each other. Except maybe you. Maybe you're already a know it all. I don't know. Thanks anyways* and ask them how that comes over? That comment does not come over as appreciative. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: HAHAHAHA I'm sorry - I was actually trying to make it sound like I respect your expertise and knowledge, like you already know everything and that you're the teacher more often than you are the student. But in hindsight man I DO sound like an incredible asshole (pardon my language)! But no, that was my bad, it was not my intention to voice it that way. I've seen you helping others elsewhere and I appreciate what you're doing for the community. Man, I feel sort of bad right now. Apologies my good man!

Comment: Hehe, no worries, apologies accepted. And for the record: Stack Overflow taught me so much of what I know, and continues to be a source of learning. Never stop being curious!

Comment: Dude, I'll be expecting to see you around more - I'm starting to increasingly spend disproportionate amount of time on SO... But I honestly don't get how some of the top contributors even manage to be so active; it's like they're constantly refreshing the Questions page or something - which I think is incredibly selfless and amazing. Anyways, SO is telling me to avoid extended discussions in comments so I'll gladly heed its advice, hehe. I'll be sure to give back to the SO community I have only taken so much from - P.S. I still feel bad about sounding belligerent, haha!

Comment: Kudos for this reaction. We all need to [relearn this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ten-commandments-of-egoless-programming/) from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in Python using list comprehension.
ex:

```
a= [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (1, 4)]
[i for i in a if i[0] == 1]
```

Will give you:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Indexing is the simplest but if you wanted to use syntax similar to your example where you wanted to  assign the first value to a variable and ignore the rest you could use  python3's [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

```
In [3]: [a for a,*_ in l]
Out[3]: [1, 1, 2]
```

Or with the any logic:

```
In [4]: l = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]

In [5]: any(a == 1 for a,*_ in l)
Out[5]: True
```

Or mimicking any without the function call:

```
In [23]: l = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
In [24]: g = (a  for a,*_ in l)

In [25]: 1 in g
Out[25]: True

In [26]: list(g)
Out[26]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

number of element in tuple could be handled also.

```
>>> import operator
>>> mylist = [(1,2), (1,5), (4,5,8)]
>>> any(i==1 for i  in map(operator.itemgetter(0), mylist))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want `filter()`, not `any()`:

```
tuple_list = [(1,5), (1,7), (2,3)]
for pair in filter(lambda pair: (pair[0] == 1), tuple_list):
    print "Second value {pair[1]} found from {pair}".format(pair=pair)
...
Second value 5 found from (1, 5)
Second value 7 found from (1, 7)
```

The [filter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) method is great because you can provide a function directly to it. This lets you specify a certain key to filter on, etc. To simplify it further, use a lambda expression to make the entire thing into a one-liner.

Comment: The purpose of my answer is to show the Python 2 filter() method specifically as a correction to the any() method; not to necessarily show the cleanest way. Also, according to post OP is already aware of list comprehensions.