# Using any() and all() on multiIndex DataFrame while slicing via .xs: strange behavior or just me?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, any

I am fairly new to Python and this community so please forgive my amateurish attempts to explain my profound confusion on something that is most likely very obvious. Anyway..

I have a dataframe called "data". It is multiIndexed with 2 levels consisting of: "date" and "farts".

There is a single column called: "integrated_daily_difference".

You can assume "farts" is of type: 'pandas.core.index.Index' and was created via: 
`farts = data.index.levels[1]`

Now lets imagine I would like take a slice view of my dataframe at an arbitrary index value in farts: i.e. farts[1]

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1)
```

Computer:

```
                  integrated_daily_difference
        date    
2015-05-21 00:00:00+00:00    0.000000
2015-05-22 00:00:00+00:00    0.000000
2015-05-26 00:00:00+00:00   -0.024497
2015-05-27 00:00:00+00:00   -0.051144
2015-05-28 00:00:00+00:00   -0.079841
2015-05-29 00:00:00+00:00   -0.106666
2015-06-01 00:00:00+00:00   -0.131245
2015-06-02 00:00:00+00:00   -0.157428
2015-06-03 00:00:00+00:00   -0.184057
2015-06-04 00:00:00+00:00   -0.209755
2015-06-05 00:00:00+00:00   -0.234588
2015-06-08 00:00:00+00:00   -0.262365
2015-06-09 00:00:00+00:00   -0.291890
2015-06-10 00:00:00+00:00   -0.320943
2015-06-11 00:00:00+00:00   -0.352627
2015-06-12 00:00:00+00:00   -0.381425
2015-06-15 00:00:00+00:00   -0.404055
```

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1) < 0
```

Computer:

```
                integrated_daily_difference
         date   
2015-05-21 00:00:00+00:00   False
2015-05-22 00:00:00+00:00   False
2015-05-26 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-05-27 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-05-28 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-05-29 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-01 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-02 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-03 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-04 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-05 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-08 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-09 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-10 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-11 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-12 00:00:00+00:00   True
2015-06-15 00:00:00+00:00   True
```

I assume this returns whether or not a value exists for any location within my sliced dataframe so the result is True?

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any()
```

Computer:

```
integrated_daily_difference    True
dtype: bool
```

OK, this all kind of makes sense. Now for the weird stuff..

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any() < 0
```

Computer:

```
integrated_daily_difference    False
dtype: bool
```

**Huh....?**

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 0) < 0
```

Computer:

```
integrated_daily_difference    False
dtype: bool
```

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 1) < 0
```

Computer:

```
       date
2015-05-21 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-22 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-26 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-27 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-28 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-29 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-01 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-02 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-03 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-04 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-05 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-08 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-09 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-10 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-11 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-12 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-15 00:00:00+00:00    False
```

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 1) <= 0
```

Computer:

```
        date
2015-05-21 00:00:00+00:00     True
2015-05-22 00:00:00+00:00     True
2015-05-26 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-27 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-28 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-05-29 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-01 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-02 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-03 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-04 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-05 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-08 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-09 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-10 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-11 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-12 00:00:00+00:00    False
2015-06-15 00:00:00+00:00    False
```

Me:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 0) <= 0
```

Computer:

```
integrated_daily_difference    False
dtype: bool
```

**Then my computer started laughing maniacally at me and my head exploded...**

But more seriously, what is going on here? My goal was to going to just try to check if all or any values in my single column dataframe meet a condition and return a boolean True or False. I don't seem to be using any() correctly, so I'm seeking help.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me define what any means according to the documentation of pandas-

> Return whether any element is True over requested axis

Now when you write -

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any()
```

It just checks whether any of the values is truthy or not **but** as there is no condition given it'll just check the numbers, which means 0 will be taken as False and and any other number as True. Now as **there are** numbers other that 0, it returns True.

Now you check -

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any() < 0
```

But True is 1 and False is 0 when represented as integers so it returns False as the output to `data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any()` is True which is 1. So if you'll check

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any() == 1
```

it'll return True.

Now lets see what happens when you do -

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 1) <= 0
```

First you have changed the axis, now `data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 1)` returns just Trues and Falses according to the values (True/1 for values other than 0 and False/0 for values which are 0). Now as the first two values are 0s/False **and it satisfies the condition** "<= 0" Its gives you the output which you see. Try doing -

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any(axis = 1) == 1
```

and you'll get the just opposite output.

**Contrary to any(), all() works differently...** It returns true if all are True or all are False else it just returns False.

***And just to mention -***

`any` and `or` OR `all` and `and` are not the same if you might think....
or and and are bitwise operations and they follow [short circuit evaluation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) but any and all being functions they'll walk through all the conditions.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thank you! I actually went a little deeper and tried the following:                                                                                      mylist = [1,2,3,4,0,-1]
print 'test 1:', all(mylist) > -1
print 'test 2:', all(i > -1  for i in mylist)                                                                                                        Test 1 printed True and Test 2 printed False. I assume this is due to True(1) and False(0) both being > -1 for the first case, and when evaluated in a generator it behaves differently..

Comment: let be break down your first try, `all(mylist)` again there is no condition, but as the list contains a 0 it'll return False which is numerically 0, that why when you test it with "> -1" it'll return True.

Comment: and in the second one, you are testing on a list of booleans! i > -1 will return False for -1 which'll lead to overall False, try >= -1 and you'll get True! Its just the base concept which you have to keep in mind....."Return True if any element of the iterable is true." - for any and "Return True if all elements of the iterable are true " - for all

Comment: check it out -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work

Comment: Is there a way to force it to evaluate the actual numerical equivalency of the condition instead of interpreting the integer values as boolean True's or False's? Like in the first Test1 case: instead of -1 > -1 evaluating as True due to -1 being > False? 0 is > -1 but -1 isn't so I'm still not sure why it returns True for all(mylist) > -1

Answer (score 2):

Consider this simple series:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 3, 10))

ser
Out[78]: 
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    2
8    0
9    0
dtype: int32
```

Let's say you want to do the comparison `ser < 2`, it will return a boolean array:

```
ser < 2
Out[79]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Now, if you want to check whether any of them is smaller than 2, you need to call `any` on this array.

```
(ser < 2).any()
Out[81]: True
```

This will return `True` if at least one of the values in `ser < 2` array is `True`. `.all()` is similar:

```
(ser < 2).all()
Out[82]: False
```

Since not all of them are True, it returns False. If you change it to:

```
(ser < 3).all()
Out[83]: True
```

Because it checks the `(ser < 3)` array and all elements in that array are `True`.

Now let's try `ser.any()`:

```
ser.any()
Out[84]: True
```

Here, you are checking if any of the values in the *original* array is `True` (If 0 is True, if 1 is True etc). The values in this array are integers, not booleans. They are evaluated as `True` if they are not equal to 0. So, since you have at least one non-zero in that array, it returns `True`.

Now, if I check `ser.any() < 0` it will return `False`:

```
ser.any() < 0
Out[85]: False
```

It is because this expression evaluates to `True < 0`:

```
True < 0
Out[86]: False
```

It is `False` because `True` is not smaller than 0. What you are doing is similar:

```
data.xs(farts[1], level = 1).any() < 0
```

It first executes `any()` on that section, and returns `True` because that section has non-zero elements. If you actually want to check whether any of them is smaller than 0, you should type:

```
(data.xs(farts[1], level = 1) < 0).any()
```

`(data.xs(farts[1], level = 1) < 0)` will create a boolean array and if any of the elements in that array is `True`, `.any()` will return `True` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. very helpful :)