# what should I do when I have to compare multiple status with if statement in python?

Tags: python

Supposed that hi has hi[0]~hi[200] this range , and I want to proceed if statement only if hi[0~200] are include 1. 
If one of hi list has rather than 1 (ex) hi[5]==2), if statement should not proceed, but else statement runs.
What should I do..?
if hi[0]==1 and hi[1]==1 and ... etc
is this the only way?

```
if hi[]==1:
    i =1
else:
    i=2
```

Comment: You're looking for the `any` or `all` keywords:  `if all(h == 1 for h in hi):`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work <-- this is what I should have set as the dupe.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein But you don't need `all()` for this necessarily, like `set(hi) == {1}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands that works, but I think it creates a set (and hashes) where an iteration would be faster. You're not reusing the `set`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands From the Zen of Python [Pep 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`  Which sounds more like "the one way": using sets in a valid but not intuitive way, or using a python keyword?  Also, OP specifically requests short circuiting behavior, which isn't in the sets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to check if all items within a range of the array have the value `1`?

You can do this by checking if any item is equal to 1 using `any` and a generator expression:

```
if any(item != 1 for item in hi[start:end]):
    print("Error")
else:
    # Ok
```

Comment: You could also use early stopping with a generator: `if any(hi[start:end], lambda item: item != 1)`

Comment: what I want to do is, when the value of  all items in hi is 1 , I want to put value 1 in i

Comment: This doesn't work, because [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) doesn't take a key/function argument. You "generally" use it with generator expressions: `any(x != 1 for x in hi[start:end])`

Comment: @BenHoyt oops just copy/pasted the suggestion from arya, rolling back.

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if all the values in a given range are equal to `1`, you need `all`:

```
hi = [1]*10

print(all(x == 1 for x in hi[0:7]))
```

returns `True` because all elements from 0 to 6 (inclusive) are 1. Now:

```
hi[5] = 5

print(all(x == 1 for x in hi[0:7]))
```

returns `False` because not all elements from 0 to 6 are 1

Answer (score -1):

Just loop through it like so:

```
for i, el in enumerate(hi):
    if el != 1:  # go to the next iteration without doing anything else
        continue
    else:
        # your code goes here
```

> EDIT: based on OP's comment on @Andre's answer:

```
i = 1 if all(x == 1 for x in hi) else 0
```

Comment: `for el in hi: if el == 1: # do something` would work too.

Comment: Sure. Is that why I have a -1 now?

Comment: Nope I am not the one who downvoted and actually I do not know why your answer got downvoted.