# Finding the value of a particular index in a Python list

Tags: python, list, nltk

I have a simple python program.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

negation ='no','not','never'.split(',')
list2 = 'miss,loss,gone,give up,lost'.split(',')
sentence = 'loss money'

if any(word in list2 for word in word_tokenize(sentence)) and (any(word in     
list2 for word in word_tokenize(sentence))[-1:])not in negation :
  print 'sad'
else:
  print 'not sad'
```

This make error which is

```
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What I need here, I want to check if any word in the sentence is in the list2. If yes, then want to check its before index value is in the negation list or not. if yes it should be "not sad".

For an example "I miss him" should sad, "I not miss him" should be not sad.

Can anyone help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write the second part of your `if` well.
You first look at `any(word in list2 for word in word_tokenize(sentence))` which returns a boolean. Then you try to extract the last element of this boolean (`[-1]`) which return an error.

No need to use `nltk` library here, you can do it with just `.split()`:

```
negation ='no,not,never'.split(',')
list2 = 'miss,loss,gone,give up,lost'.split(',')

def f(sentence):
    if any(word in list2 for word in sentence.split()) and not any(word in negation for word in sentence.split()):
        print 'sad'
    else:
        print 'not sad'

l = ['loss money', 'I miss him', 'I not miss him']
for e in l:
    f(e)
# Outputs: sad / sad / not sad
```

**edit** New version to take into account @Baldrickk good remark.
I took two more cases into consideration. It prints 'happy' if no words belong to `list2`. If several words belongs to `list2`, it checks every previous words and not just the first one.

```
negation = {'no', 'not', 'never'}
list2 = {'miss', 'loss', 'gone', 'give up', 'lost'}

def f(sentence):
    s = sentence.split()
    l = [s.index(word) for word in s if word in list2]
    # Will returns list of indices (of sentence) where word is in list2
    if len(l) > 0:
        for e in l:
            # Check previous word
            if s[e-1] not in negation:
                print 'sad'
            else:
                print 'not sad'
    else:
        print 'happy'

l = ['loss money', 'I miss him', 'I not miss him', 'happy new year', 'I am not here I am gone']
for e in l:
    f(e)
# sad / sad / not sad / happy / sad
```

Comment: note, you are not looking for the preceding word when a match to list2 is found, just for a negation to be present. "I am not here I am gone" would return `"not sad"` with your code, when the described algorithm would return `"sad"`

Comment: @Baldrickk Thanks for your comment, I didn't notice! I updated to fix this issue :)

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Nuageux Can I use this function within a Lambda Expression?

Comment: new version is nice, I do like the finding the indexes, that's quite smart.  Of course it breaks on input like: `'miss him? happy I am not'` (this comes back `'not sad'` when like my solution, it should be `'sad'`.)  I'll leave the _why_ it breaks to you.

Comment: Is it possible to write this function inside a lambda expression?

Comment: @Baldrickk I knew I should have left the exception for the *Yoda* style case. If `e==0` then I should always print 'not sad'.

Comment: if `e==0` then you want `'sad'` according to the question.  he isn't looking for `'sad I am not'` to be `'not sad'` as my erronous input example shows, you would need to understand the whole line to interpret meaning if you mean to do that.( `'sad I am not'` is happy and `'sad I am, happy I am not'` is sad)

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of problems here, for starters:

- If you are going to be looking through sets of words, use sets, not lists. e.g. `negations={'no','not','never'}`
- `'give up'` will never be found as a token in a sentence.
- `any()` returns a boolean (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)) for how it works.
- `listobj[-1:]` returns the slice of the list with only the last element
- you are not trying to extract items from a list or container, as `any()` returns a boolean, you are trying to treat a boolean as a container.  This is what is causing the error you can see.

I suggest you break down your problem into more logical steps rather than jumping straight into list comprehensions / generators.
Where you want to access items in a list based on the position of others, I recommend starting with a indexed for loop:

```
for index, value in enumerate(var):
    last_word=var[index-1] if index > 0 else None
```

And do operations like word tokenisation only once, no need to keep doing it over and over.

Example solution:

```
def sad_sentence(sentence):
    wordlist=sentence.split()
    negations={'no','not','never'}
    negphrases={'miss','loss','gone','give up','lost'}

    for index, word in enumerate(wordlist):
        last_word=wordlist[index-1] if index > 0 else None
        if word in negphrases:
            if last_word in negations:
                print 'not sad'
            else:
                print 'sad'
            break;
        print 'not sad'
```

This results in:

```
>>> sad_sentence("I am not gone")
not sad
>>> sad_sentence("I am not here I am gone")
sad
>>>
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I corrected lot of mistakes while go through your answer