# Pandas drop rows with value less than a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to delete rows that contain only values that are less than 10 and greater than 25. My sample dataframe will look like this:

```
a   b   c  
1   2   3  
4   5   16  
11  24  22  
26  50  65
```

**Expected Output:**

```
a   b   c  
1   2   3  
4   5   16   
26  50  65
```

So if the row contains any value less than 10 or greater than 25, then the row will stay in dataframe, otherwise, it needs to be dropped.

Is there any way I can achieve this with Pandas instead of iterating through all the rows?

Comment: Good luck. I hope you get your rows taken care of.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is not how you ask a question on SO. You should show some minimal effort on your part. If you have the resources to ask a question here, you have the resources to do a little searching yourself.

Comment: why are the first and last rows still in your expected output? this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you explain your deletion criteria better? Do you drop a row if **any** of the values are less than 10 and greater than 25? or **all** of the values? The example input and output doesn't make sense

Comment: If the row has any one value which is less than 10 or greater than 25, then the row will stay in dataframe else it needs to be dropped.

Comment: @PaulH Sorry for the confusion..just updated the question.

Comment: It's clarified but the end of the question now contradicts the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and return the results to a new column called 'Keep'. You can then use this column to drop rows that you don't need.

```
import pandas as pd
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[11,24,22],[26,50,65]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['a','b','c']) #Set up sample dataFrame

df['keep'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(any([(x < 10) or (x > 25) for x in row])), axis = 1)
```

The `any()` function returns a generator. Calling `sum(generator)` simply returns the sum of all the results stored in the generator.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) on how `any()` works. 
Apply function still iterates over all the rows like a for loop, but the code looks cleaner this way. I cannot think of a way to do this without iterating over all the rows.

Output:

```
    a   b   c  keep
0   1   2   3     1
1   4   5   6     1
2  11  24  22     0
3  26  50  65     1


df = df[df['keep'] == 1] #Drop unwanted rows
```

Comment: Great answer! I'm new to pandas and was wondering if this is more efficient to "just loop" over the dataframe. I don't know how panda's dataframe is implemented under the hood but this seems like iterating over it twice.
Could you please point me to some explanation on that?

Comment: Apply function is just syntactic sugar for a loop. Even if you wrote a for loop to iterate over all rows, I am not sure if there is a way to drop rows on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pandas boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
dropped_df = df.loc[((df<10) | (df>25)).any(1)]
```

- `df<10` will return a boolean df
- `|` is the OR operator
- `.any(1)` returns any true element over the axis 1 (rows) [see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)
- `df.loc[]` then filters the dataframe based on the boolean df

Answer (score 1):

I really like using masking for stuff like this; it's clean so you can go back and read your code. It's faster than using `.apply` too which is effectively for looping. Also, it avoids setting by copy warnings.

This uses boolean indexing like Prageeth's answer. But the difference is I like how you can save the boolean index as a separate variable for re-use later. I often do that so I don't have to modify the original dataframe or create a new one and just use `df[mask]` wherever I want that cropped view of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2,3],
    [4,5,16],
    [11,24,22],
    [26,50,65]],
    columns=['a','b','c']
)

#use a mask to create a fully indexed boolean dataframe, 
#which avoids the SettingWithCopyWarning:
#https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
mask = (df > 10) & (df < 25)
print(mask)
"""
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False  False   True
2   True   True   True
3  False  False  False
"""

print(df[mask])
"""
      a     b     c
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN  16.0
2  11.0  24.0  22.0
3   NaN   NaN   NaN
"""

print(df[mask].dropna())
"""
      a     b     c
2  11.0  24.0  22.0
"""

#one neat things about using masking is you can invert them too with a '~'
print(~mask)
"""
       a      b      c
0   True   True   True
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3   True   True   True
"""

print( df[~mask].dropna())
"""
      a     b     c
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
3  26.0  50.0  65.0
"""

#you can also combine masks
mask2 = mask & (df < 24)
print(mask2)
"""
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False  False   True
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
"""

#and the resulting dataframe (without dropping the rows that are nan or contain any false mask)
print(df[mask2])
"""
      a   b     c
0   NaN NaN   NaN
1   NaN NaN  16.0
2  11.0 NaN  22.0
3   NaN NaN   NaN
"""
```