# How to retrieve only those words from file which have noun tags?

Tags: python, arrays, pos-tagger

I have a program to extract only those words from file which have pos tags present pos-tags variable. My program does not give any error but it does not show anything as well. It only executes. Here is my sample input:

```
[['For,IN', ',,,', 'We,PRP', 'the,DT', 'divine,NN', 'caused,VBD', 'apostle,NN', 'We,PRP', 'vouchsafed,VBD', 'unto,JJ', 'Jesus,NNP', 'the,DT', 'son,NN', 'of,IN', 'Mary,NNP', 'all,DT', 'evidence,NN', 'of,IN', 'the,DT', 'truth,NN', ',,,', 'and,CC', 'strengthened,VBD', 'him,PRP', 'with,IN', 'holy,JJ'], [ 'be,VB', 'nor,CC', 'ransom,NN', 'taken,VBN', 'from,IN', 'them,PRP', 'and,CC', 'none,NN', '\n']]
```

Here is my code:

```
import nltk
import os.path
import re
import os
sample_text4='E://QuranCopies45.txt'
file2 = open(sample_text4,'r',encoding='utf8')
arr=[]
for line in file2.readlines():
    words=re.split(' ',line)
    words=[line.replace('/',",")for line in words]
    arr.append(words)
pos_tags = ('NN', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS')
nouns=[s.split(',')[0] for sub in arr for s in sub if s.endswith(pos_tags)]
print(nouns)
```

Here is my expected output:

```
[ 'divine', 'apostle','Jesus', 'son','Mary',  'evidence',  'truth',  'ransom', 'none']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, but you'd need to fix your `if` statement. The goal is to check if *any* of the elements from `pos_tags` exists in those list items... so, use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)!

```
>>> [j.split(',')[0] for i in arr for j in i if any(j.endswith(p) for p in pos_tags)]     
['divine',
 'apostle',
 'Jesus',
 'son',
 'Mary',
 'evidence',
 'truth',
 'ransom',
 'none']
```

`any` performs short circuiting comparison, checking to see if any of the elements in `pos_tags` is present at the end of a list item. `any` returns `True` the moment it finds a tag for which the condition is satisfied. Otherwise, if, after iterating through `pos_tags`, none of the conditions are `True`, then `any` returns `False`.

For more information, see [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work).

Comment: still it is not doing anything.

Comment: i saved it but it runs without any error and shows nothing.

Comment: @Nisa Did you assign it to a variable and print it out?

Comment: yes i did assigned it to variable and printed it but it runs and shows nothing.

Comment: @Nisa Without any more information, there's nothing I can do. As you can see, it worked in the MWE in my answer, so it's something on your side, not mine.