# Python any() function does not act as expected for list of negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, any

I am trying to compare a list of numbers in an if statement with the any() function. I am using python 3.6 in Spyder. The code in question is:

```
if any(lst) >= 1:
    do_some_stuff
```

lst is actually generated by `list(map(my_func, other_lst))` but after diagnosing my problem I get two behaviors as shown below with my actual lst passed to the any() function:

```
any([1.535, 1.535, 1.535]) >= 1
>>True
```

Which is expected.

```
any([-0.676, -0.676, -0.676]) >= 1
>>True
```

Which is **not** expected.

I've delved deeper and found that any number I can put in lst that is less than 0 yields `True` in my if statement. Also, converting the 1 to a float doesn't help. After reading ["truth value testing"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work), and extensive time trying to learn the behavior within my program, I am at a loss. Please help, I am pretty new to python. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `any([-0.676, -0.676, -0.676]) >= 1` is doing what you think it's doing. Perhaps you meant: `any(x >= 1 for x in [-0.676, -0.676, -0.676])`?

Comment: Why its *not expected*?

Comment: You gave a link to the documentation for truth value testing, but it appears you didn't read it.

Comment: Total newbie here. Sorry. I see now why everything I was doing is expected. Thank you for everyone's time and extremely fast responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the wrong thing. You are comparing the *result of any* to 1.

`any(mylist)` will return true if any element of the list is nonzero. True is greater than or equal to 1.

So this

```
any(mylist)>=1
```

is equivalent to just

```
any(mylist)
```

What you mean is

```
any(x>=1 for x in mylist)
```

Comment: Yes, I just realized this pretty much 30 seconds after posting. Sorry, and thank you for your time. Total newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

> any(iterable)
>
> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If
> the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

All your `any()` expression listed will return `True`, and you are comparing `True` with 1, that is `True`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a different idea of what an iterable was. Though I just discovered the python glossary, so I will make my best effort to not let this happen again with other terms. Still working on my coding vocabulary. Thanks for your time.