# Pandas dataframe get column names with values in cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the column names which have cell values less than .2, without repeating a combination of columns. I tried this to iterate over the column names without success:

```
pvals2=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, .2,.7], 
                     'col2': [.2, 1,.01],
                     'col3': [.7,.01,1]},
                    index = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
print(pvals2)
print('---')
pvals2.transpose().join(pvals2, how='outer')
```

My goal is:

```
col3 col2 .01
#col2 col3 .01 #NOT INCLUDED (because it it a repeat)
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is one way:

```
pvals2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, .2,.7], 'col2': [.2, 1,.01], 'col3': [.7,.01,1]},
                      index = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

res = [col for col in pvals2 if (pvals2[col] < 0.2).any()]

# ['col2', 'col3']
```

To get values as well, as in your desired output, requires more specification, as a column may have more than one value less than 0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the columns and check if any value meets your conditions:

```
pvals2=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, .2,.7], 
                 'col2': [.2, 1,.01],
                 'col3': [.7,.01,1]})

cols_with_small_values = set()
for col in pvals2.columns:     
    if any(i < 0.2 for i in pvals2[col]):
        cols_with_small_values.add(col)
        cols_with_small_values.add(pvals2[col].min())

print(cols_with_small_values)


RESULT: {'col3', 0.01, 'col2'}
```

`any` is a built-in. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) has a good explanation for how `any` works. And we can use a `set` to assure each column will only appear once.

We use DataFrame.min() to get the small value that caused us to select this column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use stack and then filter out values < 0.2. Then keep the last duplicated value

```
pvals2.stack()[pvals2.stack().lt(.2)].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

---

```
col3  col2    0.01
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pvals2=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, .2,.7], 
             'col2': [.2, 1,.01],
             'col3': [.7,.01,1]},
            index = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])


pvals2.min().where(lambda x : x<0.1).dropna()
```

Output

```
col2    0.01
col3    0.01
dtype: float64
```