# Check to see if a string contains either of the strings in a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list a:

```
a = ['2005', '2006']
```

and list b:

```
b = ['2005.123', '2005.234', '2006.123', '2007.234']
```

If I wanted a list of all the elements in b that contains a string '2005', I would do:

```
[value for value in b if '2005' in str(value)]
```

But I would like a list of all the values in b that contain either of the string values in list a (list a and b can be several elements long), and this one does not work:

```
[value for value in b if ['2005', '2006'] in str(value)]
```

I would like the code to return

```
['2005.123', '2005.234', '2006.123']
```

Is there an easier way to do this, without using loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`any()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work):

```
[value for value in b if any(d in value for d in a)]
#['2005.123', '2005.234', '2006.123']
```

Also, you do not have to call `str(value)` as it's already a string.

---

**Update**: Just for fun, here's another way to do the same thing using `filter()`:

```
filter(lambda value: any(d in value for d in a), b)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. The reason for str(value) was to allow for the chance that some numbers may not have been represented as string.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for "contains" but your example has prefixes.  If it's prefixes you want use `str.startswith`, which will allow you to pass a tuple of prefixes as its first argument:

```
a_tup = tuple(a)
[value for value in b if value.startswith(a_tup)]
```