# Empty numpy array boolean contradiction

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I accidentally found something in Numpy, which I can't really understand. If I check an empty Numpy array for any true value

```
    np.array([]).any()
```

it will evaluate to false, whereas if I check all values to be true

```
    np.array([]).all()
```

it evaluates to true. This appears weird to me since no value is true but at the same time all values are true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic you are seeing is not specific to NumPy. This is a Python convention which has been implemented in NumPy:

- `any` returns `True` if any value is `True`. Otherwise `False`.
- `all` returns `True` if no value is `False`. Otherwise `True`.

See the [pseuedo-code in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to see the logic in pure Python.

In the case of `np.array([]).any()` or `any([])`, there are no `True` values, because you have a 0-dimensional array or a 0-length list. Therefore, the result is `False`.

In the case of `np.array([]).all()` or `all([])`, there are no `False` values, because you have a 0-dimensional array or a 0-length list. Therefore, the result is `True`.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a bug, it returns `True` because all values are not equal to zero which is the criteria for returning `True` see the following [note](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

> Not a Number (NaN), positive infinity and negative infinity evaluate
>   to True because these are not equal to zero.

compare with the following:

```
In[102]:

np.array([True,]).all()
Out[102]: True
```

This would be equivalent to an array full of `NaN` which would return `True`

Comment: I didn't think it was a bug. I just could not understand it. But now it makes sense. So while any() is searching for true's all() is searching for false's. Thank you for your help...

Comment: I think the possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work explains the behaviour, so I think this is the convention that `numpy` is following, we could mark this as a dupe but let's see if others agree

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior.

It is not possible to find a value that is true, so `np.array([]).any()` is False

For every value in the array, this value is False (It is easy to check, because there are no values in the array, so you don't have to check anything).