# Perl pendant for Python Built-in Functions `all` and `any`

Tags: python, perl, perl-data-structures

Are there Perl functions that work like Python functions `all` or `any`? [This answer from Jobin is a short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42152298/7421890) of how both functions are working.

I want to determine (without loop) if all error-msg's are `defined and ne ""` in the following structure:

```
$VAR1 = [{
  'row' => [{
      err_msg => "msg1",
      a => "a1",
      b => "b1"
    },
    {
      err_msg => "msg2",
      a => "a2",
      b => "b2"
    }]
},
{
  'row' => [{
      err_msg => "msg3",
      a => "a3",
      b => "b3"
    },
    {
      err_msg => "msg4",
      a => "a4",
      b => "b4"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to perform the check without looping, but you could indeed use `all` to do this.

```
use List::Util qw( all );

my $ok =
   all {
      all { $_->{err_msg} }
         @{ $_->{row} }
   }
      @$VAR1;
```

or

```
use List::Util qw( all );

my $ok =
   all { $_->{err_msg} }
      map { @{ $_->{row} } }
         @$VAR1;
```

The first version is more efficient because it only looks at a group if all the previous groups check out ok, whereas the second version unconditionally does work for every group. This difference is unlikely to matter, though.

Comment: `all { $_->{err_msg} }` also considers `0` an invalid value. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: first version unfortunately always returns `true`, even for non-existing keys. But second version works great :)

Comment: `all { length $_->{err_msg} }` will be true for 0 but not an empty string or undef. But note it will warn on undef before Perl 5.12.

Comment: @Chris For what input do you see that? (What do you mean by "_non-existing keys_"?)  It works in my tests.

Comment: @Chris. The first version works fine. For example, if I comment out the first `err_msg` line in your data structure, it returns false.