# How to create an if statement for elements within a list?

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can create an if statement that does something to a list as long as there is at least one value in the list that meets the if statement's requirements.

For example, given a list

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y=[1,2,3,4]
z=[1,2,3,8]
```

I want to create an if statement where if the list contains elements whose values are between 5 and 10, then the list appends ***.

Meaning, after the if statement, the results would be

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,***]
y=[1,2,3,4]
z=[1,2,3,8,***]
```

since both x and z contains elements that are between 5 and 10, they receive the ***.

Comment: What is `***`??

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19389490/4996248

Comment: This sounds like homework. At the very least you should show us what you have tried

Comment: You should loop over the list (or use a list comprehension) to verify that the condition is satisfied and in case do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most succinct way to do this in Python 3 is to use a generator expression:

```
if any(5 < x < 10 for x in lst):
  lst.append('***')
```

Here is a working [example](https://repl.it/repls/AgitatedNewServicepack).

Edit: That syntax is kind of mind blowing, thanks for the edit and the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this. Test if any of the elements match your condition using a generator expression and the `any()` function.

```
x = [1,2,3,4] #two lists for testing
y = [5]       

if any(5 <= i <= 10 for i in x):
        x.append("***")

if any(5 <= i <= 10 for i in y):
        y.append("***")

print(x,y)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, '***']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i=0
while i<len(x):
  if x[i]>5 and x[i]<10: #if any item of list is between 5 and 10 break loop
    break
  i+=1

if i<len(x): #check if i less than len(x) this means that loop 'broken' until the end
  x.append('***')
```

Comment: You should try to do this without `while`, iterator and `break`. Your code is too complex. Do not forget the Zen of python and Keep It Simple Stupid (KISS).