# How can I select outer item in a sublist on the basis of matching of items from my other list?

Tags: python

I have a list like the one below:

```
mylist = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, []], [6, [0]]]
```

The inner list is `[1, 2], [1], [0, 2]` and so on.

The outer list is `[0], [1], [2]` and so on.

**CASE 1**: If the inner list has one item from `myOtherlist` and does not share this inner list with another number then get the outer item. Like the one below:

INPUT:

```
myOtherlist = [2, 3]
```

OUTPUT:

```
outer_item_list = [3]
```

**CASE 2**: If the inner list has all the items from myOtherlist then get the outer item and of course if one of the items from `myOtherlist` is on its own somewhere else in `mylist`. Like the one below:

INPUT:

```
myOtherlist = [0, 2]
```

OUTPUT:

```
outer_item_list = [2, 6]
```

**CASE 3**: If the inner list has one item from `myOtherlist` and it is on its own in the inner list then get the outer item. Like the one below:

INPUT:

```
myOtherlist = [0]
```

OUTPUT:

```
outer_item = [6]
```

MY CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
outer_item_list = []

for number in list:
    for inner in mylist:
        if number in inner[1] and len(inner[1]) == 1:
            fetch_outer_number = inner[0]
            outer_item_list.append(fetch_outer_number)
            print(outer_item_list)
```

I think I have managed to do CASE 3, but I need some help with CASE 1 and CASE 2.

NOTE: `mylist` is a common input for all 3 cases.

Comment: You are asking two broad questions simultaneously. Split them into two

Comment: how are you defining *inner*/*outer* lists? Could you explain that and maybe show what the end result of any process running across `mylist` would actually result in?

Comment: @JonClements Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `mylist` and check if all of the elements in the second sublist are available in `myOtherlist`:

```
def find_items(mylist, myOtherlist):
    outer_item = []
    for x, y in mylist:
        if y and all(z in myOtherlist for z in y):
            outer_item.append(x)          
    return outer_item
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> mylist = [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1]], [2, [0, 2]], [3, [3]], [4, []], [5, []], [6, [0]]]
>>> find_items(mylist, [2, 3])
[3]
>>> find_items(mylist, [0, 2])
[2, 6]
>>> find_items(mylist, [0])
[6]
```

Comment: +1 for the relevent use of a `if any and all` function: [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)