# idiomatic way for checking all N'th idx elements in list

Tags: python

I want to check if all the 2nd values of a list's sub-lists are OK.

```
ls = [['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 2]]
```

How can I check that `ls` does not have all `None`'s in the 2nd index of its sub-lists without for loop?

Would something like `filter(lambda sublist, idx=1, value=None: sublist[idx] == value, ls)` do the trick?

Comment: "does not have all None's" means you want at least one value to be non-None? Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will look for the first entry for which the condition is `True` (and therefore not necessarily iterate over your whole list):

```
any(y is not None for x_, y in ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [all (or any) keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work) and [list comprehension syntax](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
ls = [['a', None], ['b', None], ['c', 2]]

all_none = all(l[1] is None for l in ls)
one_not_none = any(l[1] is not None for l in ls)

print(all_none)  # >> False
```

Comment: just fyi, this is not a list comprehension. It's a *generator expression*.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but syntax is the same and I had this link for documentation on list comprehensions so... But you're right.