# Loop over list with and condition

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write a code for below pseudocode

```
for all element in list do
    match and condition
    if all match
       return True
```

for example, List A=[1,2,3,4,5],B=10

What I want is like

```
def match():
    for i in range(len(A)):
      if B%A[0]==0 and B%A[1]==0 and B%A[2]==0 and B%A[3]==0 and B%A[4]==0: #Generate all these 
        #and condition one by one
        #automatically in this function
          return True
```

How can I do?

NOTE:I am asking about write code match and condition with a loop, not write a remainder

Comment: Check out the python `all` function. Here is a good introduction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
result = all( [(B%a==0) for a in A] )
```

Comment: You can remove the `[ ]`, `result = all(B % x == 0 for x in A)`. You can save some memory since this wont generate a list

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I intentionally wrote it that way to make it easier to understand for OP

Comment: Does adding `[]` make it easier to understand?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I hope it does. The original problem was not related to using extra memory or using the minimum amount of characters, more like to understanding or basic structures and possible operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pythonic one liner

`result = all(B % x == 0 for x in A)`

Or maybe in a slightly more familiar syntax

```
res = True
for x in A:
    if B % x != 0:
        res = False
        break
```