# how does any() and all() work? it returns True when I expect False

Tags: python

So I have read all the documentation on programiz and I still can't figure out why these run as True.
Code:

```
yey = [False]
yea = [0]

print(all((yea, yey)))
print(any((yea, yey)))
```

output:

```
True
True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: btw progamiz is a terrible way to learn any language

Comment: not really @TomRon Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the single element inside your lists are `0` and `False`:

```py
yey = [False]
yea = [0]
```

But when you use `yea` and `yey`, in all and any, the check is "is the list empty or not?

```
print(all((yea, yey)))
print(any((yea, yey)))
```

Will return `True` because the lists are not `empty`, but if you look at the first elements for example:

```
print(all((yea[0], yey[0])))
print(any((yea[0], yey[0])))
```

returns

```
False
False
```

Here is a function you could use to check multiple lists:

```
yey = [False]
yea = [0]

def any_list(lists): return any([any(i) for i in lists])
def all_list(lists): return all([all(i) for i in lists])

print(all_list((yea, yey)))   # False
print(any_list((yea, yey)))   # False
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `bool(yea)` evaluates to `True` (list has element)

```
>>> all((yea, yey))
True
>>>
>>> (yea, yey)
([0], [False])
>>>
>>> (bool(yea), bool(yey))
(True, True)
>>>
```

So,

```
>>> all((True, True))
True
>>> any((True, True))
True
>>>
```

And

```
>>> all((False, 0))
False
>>>
>>> any((False, 0))
False
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what I misunderstood now!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want something more like

```
>>> all(yea)
False
>>> any(yea)
False
```

These would make even more sense if `yea` and `yay` were each a list with multiple elements rather than a single value.

Comment: Yea it works that way but I was just not understanding why it does not work with two arguments