# Python if statement on list of strings with any statements on desirable / exclusion lists of keywords

Tags: python, list, if-statement, any

I'm trying to check whether a list of string items have substrings belong to a list of strings (desirable list) but not to another list of string (exclusion list). Here's an example below of what I'm trying to do:

```
worthwhile_gifts = []

wishlist = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'pony']

gifts = ['a dog', 'a bulldog', 'a cartload of cats', 'Mickey doghouse', 'blob fish']

# Checking that various Xmas gifts include items from wishlist
for gift in gifts:
    if any(i in gift for i in wishlist):
        worthwhile_gifts.append(gift)
```

Looking at the result, we get what we expect this way

```
>>> print(worthwhile_gifts)
['a dog', 'a bulldog', 'a cartload of cats', 'Mickey doghouse']
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to check the list of gifts against the following two lists (I want items form `wishlist` but not from `blocklist`) and I'm having a hard time generating the if statement condition with two `any` statements in it

```
wishlist = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'poney']
blocklist = ['bulldog', 'caterpillar', 'workhorse']

# Expected result would exclude 'bulldog'
>>> print(worthwhile_gifts)
['a dog', 'a cartload of cats', 'Mickey doghouse']
```

Any idea how to construct this if statement? I tried `if (any(i in gift for i in wishlist)) and (any(i in gift for i not in blocklist))` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you need to check that the gift is not in the blacklist (`all` & `not int`)

```
wishlist = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'poney']
blocklist = ['bulldog', 'caterpillar', 'workhorse']

gifts = ['a dog', 'a bulldog', 'a cartload of cats', 'Mickey doghouse', 'blob fish']

worthwhile_gifts = []

for gift in gifts:
    if any(i in gift for i in wishlist) and all(i not in gift for i in blocklist):
        worthwhile_gifts.append(gift)

print(worthwhile_gifts)
```

Result:

```
['a dog', 'a cartload of cats', 'Mickey doghouse']
```

Comment: Thanks @rdas - this works perfect. Checking this other post really helped me understand why I needed to resort to `all` in the second statement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work