# How does the "any()" function work with a iteration like "x in y for x in z"?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to understand what is going on inside any function. Can't understand the loop inside it. Can anyone break it down for me?

```
with open(host_temp,'r+') as f:
    c = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in c:
        if not any(website in line for website in blocked_sites):
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: That's a generator expression. Are you familiar with list comprehensions? If yes, you can imagine that call as `any([website in line for website in blocked_sites])`. If no, consider learning about them: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function returns `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.

The syntax inside the `any` function in this example (`x in y for x in z`) is known as a [**generator expression**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

> [The syntax for generator expressions] is the same as for comprehensions, except that it is enclosed in parentheses instead of brackets or curly braces.

The main difference between a generator and a comprehension, is that a generator evaluates lazily (as needed) whereas a comprehension evaluates all of the variables immediately. More precisely, a generator expression yields a new generator object that lazily evaluates the variables whenever its [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.__next__) method is called.

In this case, the generator expression is iterating through a container called `blocked_sites`. For each `website` in `blocked_sites`, it is checking if the website is contained in the current `line` of the file.

So, if any blocked website is found in a line of the file, then that line is skipped.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the ongoing process within the loop? I'm trying to understand what is happening when it says: website in line for website in blocked_sites ... is it taking a line from the text file that I opened and trying to match it with the blocked list items? Is that what is going there?

Answer (score 1):

To complement Christopher Peisert's answer I split the code into how one might extent the `any` statement to make it more readable (however not preferable code-vice).

```
with open (host_temp,'r+') as f:
  c = f.readlines()
  f.seek(0)
  for line in c:
    website_in_blocked_sites = False
    for website in blocked_sites:
      if website in line:
        website_in_blocked_sites = True
    if website_in_blocked_sites:
      f.write(line)
  f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is similar to this (providing the long version for this code):

```
for line in c:
    is_website_in_line = []
    for website in blocked_sites:
        is_website_in_line.append(website in line) # website in line check if a string is within another, so it returns either True or False
    if not any(is_website_in_line) # if all of the list has False values
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`any()` will return true if any of the elements handed to it are "truthy" (same as `if x:`).  It takes in this case a generator as a parameter.  Because the comprehension code is without surrounding [] and {} and also between () the implication is that it is a generator.

```
for website in blocked_sites:
    if website in line:
        return True
return False
```