# What does for loop does after a Boolean statement?

Tags: python, for-loop

In this snippet,what **for** loop does?

```
a = input().split()
if (all([int(i) > 0 for i in a]) and any([(i) == (i)[::-1]] for i in a)):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Edit: There is a solution,you can check it out! [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: but you do understand the `any` part?

Comment: You are looking for the term `List Comprehension`.

Comment: `a` is a list of strings integers. `(all([int(i) > 0 for i in a])` checks if all the numbers in this list are greater than *0*. `any([(i) == (i)[::-1]] for i in a))` if `a` is equal to reversed `a`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Explain this code block to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as is "teach me this basic programming tool".
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
It seems that you need to look up the `any` and `all` commands.  Most tutorials will also show you *list comprehensions* and *generators*, the common ways to express arguments to those functions.

Comment: @DeepSpace yes.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks I'll look for it

Comment: @BerkeBalcı but they are the exact same construct, just using a different operation on `i`. I don't see how it's possible to understand one but not the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A structure like

```py
[atom for atom in iterable if condition(atom)]
```

is a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

---

Further-

`any()` returns `True` if at least one of the members of an iterable passed to it is [Truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Together, this creates a list where each value is conditionally True and then returns whether at least one value in that new list is Truthy

The structure you provide actually does a lot more than it needs to, because the `any()` could be made redundant (a non-empty list is Truthy, and the condition `x>0` guarantees that any entries are Truthy)

The second condition (after the `and`) seems to be some attempt to find [palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) by checking if the member is equal to itself reversed

```py
>>> "1234"[::-1]
'4321'
```

---

Finally the statement itself is Truthy or Falsey, so there's no need for an `if` at all, and it can be directly used/displayed immediately when found

Here's an enterprise version

```py
import sys

def test_substrings(sub_strings):
    for atom in sub_strings:
        if int(atom) <= 0:      # ValueError for non-int
            return False
        if atom != atom[::-1]:  # check for palindrome
            return False
    return True

sub_strings = input("enter a list of integers separated by spaces: ").split()

try:
    result = test_substrings(sub_strings)
except ValueError as ex:
    sys.exit("invalid entry (expected an integer): {}".format(
        repr(ex)))

print(str(result))
```

and a compact version

```
print(bool([x for x in input().split() if int(x) > 0 and x==x[::-1]]))
```

Beware: your example and mine will accept an empty input ("") as True