# Computational cost of any() in Python

Tags: python, built-in

What is the computational cost of using any() or not any()?

The any() built-in checks if any element is True in an iterable. I would suppose it needs to check all the elements it is applied to, so I would assume the cost to be O(n).

Comment: Refer to [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Comment: O(n); it checks every element passed as argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: None of those mentioned computational cost, hence why this is in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) it says the function any is equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
for element in iterable:
    if element:
        return True
return False
```

So we can assume the computational cost is, as you state, O(n).